# multiple file uploader that works well in JSF and IE7

Tags: jsf, upload, internet-explorer-7, file-upload

I nead a file uploader that allows you to to select multiple files at once tu upload them.

I have a seam2, jsf 1.2, richfaces3 application, we tried the richfaces uploader and uploadify but both has problems in IE7

Any hints?

Answer (score 0):

Why not write your own Upload filter. Since you are using JSF 1.2, refer to Chapter 13 of Core Java Server Faces 2nd edition book.

Comment: Wea are in a little hurry so I hoped that someone already solved that problem, I taught that this is a common problem, mybe i'm, wrong.